# JSONata, pulling data from nested objects

Tags: jsonata

I'm new to JSONata and so still getting my head around it. I need to pull data out of a nested object, for example from :

```
{
    "transaction": {
        "id": "de112b4b-82e2-4172-a89f-68724c90b692"
    },
    "domain": {
        "id": "realworld"
    },
    "listing": {
        "spanner": {
            "information": {
                "type": {
                    "VENDOR": "Charlie"
                },
                "variables": {
                },
                "uid": "08_spanner",
                "mode": {
                    "store": "bob"
                },
                "version": "1",
                "name": "Harrold"
            }
        },
        "hammer": {
            "information": {
                "type": {
                    "VENDOR": "Cliff"
                },
                "variables": {
                },
                "uid": "08_hammer",
                "mode": {
                    "store": "steve"
                },
                "version": "1",
                "name": "Mike"
            }
        },
        "wrench": {
            "information": {
                "type": {
                    "VENDOR": "Dave"
                },
                "variables": {
                },
                "uid": "08_wrench",
                "mode": {
                    "store": "bob"
                },
                "version": "1",
                "name": "Kent"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

... I need to pull out the listing data with it's "information", but without the information key. So the result would look like:

```
{
    "spanner": {
        "type": {
            "VENDOR": "Charlie"
        },
        "variables": {
        },
        "uid": "08_spanner",
        "mode": {
            "store": "bob"
        },
        "version": "1",
        "name": "Harrold"
    },
    "hammer": {
        "type": {
            "VENDOR": "Cliff"
        },
        "variables": {
        },
        "uid": "08_hammer",
        "mode": {
            "store": "steve"
        },
        "version": "1",
        "name": "Mike"
    },
    "wrench": {
        "type": {
            "VENDOR": "Dave"
        },
        "variables": {
        },
        "uid": "08_wrench",
        "mode": {
            "store": "bob"
        },
        "version": "1",
        "name": "Kent"
    }
}
```

I have been messing around on http://try.jsonata.org/ and can see how powerful the library is but so far no success at achieving this goal. Any and all help is appreciated :).

Comment: hey @thechane what does your current JS look like? that will help us figure out what might be going wrong.

Comment: Hello - for right now I am just attempting in http://try.jsonata.org/. The expression will go into a node-red flow, so no relevant JS to post.

Comment: So you are trying to access specific data from that JSON, and place that in it's own JSON? You'll have to write some code to pull those apart, so I'd suggest giving it a go and posting your results here so we can take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following expression will do this:

```
listing.$each(function($value, $key) {
  { $key: $value.information }
}) ~> $merge()
```

See http://try.jsonata.org/S17Erm85z

Comment: Thank you!! Exactly what I was looking for. This will speed up my learning for sure.